# access to navigate methods React-Big-Calendar and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

I am having a hard time using a custom toolbar with react-big-calendar and typescript. I am trying to access the original methods of 'next, prev' 'month, day, week' views. 
I have extensively read... 
https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/623
https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/818
http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-components

The custom UI is rendering fine, without errors, Now I need access to the original methods so I can manipulate the calendar.

The main problem is that my button is firing, but not actually navigating anything.

Some Issues that I think is...

-- I'm not actually using the navigateMethod like I think

--The default date and date inside BigCalendar isn't actually changing because I'm overwriting it with the same day every time I click?

-- I need to implement this example from their docs?

```
Custom views can be any React component, that implements the following interface:

interface View {
  static title(date: Date, { formats: DateFormat[], culture: string?, ...props }): string
  static navigate(date: Date, action: 'PREV' | 'NEXT' | 'DATE'): Date
}
```

Does anyone have an example I could look at???

Here is my full source code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { MainContent } from '../../../common/templates/partials'
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'
import ToolBar from 'react-big-calendar'
import Icon from 'app/common/components/Icon'
import moment from 'moment'
const styles = require('./CalendarUI.scss')

BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment) // or globalizeLocalizer

const events = [
  {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    title: 'Some title',
  },
]

class CustomToolbar extends ToolBar {

  render() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log(this.props, this)
    /* tslint:disable-next-line */
    const {label, onNavigate} = this.props as any
    return (
      <div className="rbc-toolbar">
        <div>
          {/* tslint:disable-next-line  */}
          <button onClick={() => this.props.onNavigate ? onNavigate(null as any, 'PREV') : undefined}>
            <Icon icon="B" />
          </button>
          <label className="label-date">{label}</label>
          {/* tslint:disable-next-line  */}
          <button onClick={() => this.props.onNavigate ? onNavigate(null, 'NEXT') : undefined}>
            <Icon icon="A" />
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
        <span className="rbc-btn-group">
          <button>Month</button>
          <button>Day</button>
          <button>Week</button>
        </span>

        <button className="btn btn-back">
          <Icon icon="R" />
        </button>
        <button className="btn btn-back">
          <Icon icon="meet_now" />
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const logger = (data: string) =>
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.log(data)
const CalendarUI = () => (
  <MainContent>
    <div className={styles.calendarContainer}>
      <BigCalendar
        defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
        defaultView="month"
        events={events}
        components={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
        startAccessor="startDate"
        endAccessor="endDate"
        onView={logger}
        date={moment().toDate()}
      />
    </div>
  </MainContent>
)

export default CalendarUI
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out creating a CustomToolbar component. Check out the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export interface ICustomTooolbarProps {
    view: string;
    views: string[];
    label: any;
    localizer: any;
    onNavigate: (action: any) => void;
    onView: (view: any) => void;
    onViewChange: (view: any) => void;
    messages: any;
}

export const navigateContants = {
    PREVIOUS: 'PREV',
    NEXT: 'NEXT',
    TODAY: 'TODAY',
    DATE: 'DATE'
};

export const views = {
    MONTH: 'month',
    WEEK: 'week',
    WORK_WEEK: 'work_week',
    DAY: 'day',
    AGENDA: 'agenda'
};

const CustomToolbar: React.SFC<ICustomTooolbarProps> = (props) => {
    function navigate(action) {
        props.onNavigate(action);
    }

    function viewItem(view) {
        props.onViewChange(view);
    }

    function viewNamesGroup(messages) {
        const viewNames = props.views;
        const view = props.view;

        if (viewNames.length > 1) {
            return viewNames.map((name) => (
                <button
                    type="button"
                    key={name}
                    className={css({ 'rbc-active': view === name })}
                    onClick={viewItem.bind(null, name)}>
                    {messages[name]}
                </button>
            ));
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="rbc-toolbar">
            <span className="rbc-btn-group">
                <button type="button" onClick={navigate.bind(null, navigateContants.TODAY)}>
                    Current month
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={navigate.bind(null, navigateContants.PREVIOUS)}>
                    Previous month
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={navigate.bind(null, navigateContants.NEXT)}>
                    Next month
                </button>
            </span>

            <span className="rbc-toolbar-label">{props.label}</span>

            <span className="rbc-btn-group">{viewNamesGroup(props.messages)}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CustomToolbar;
```

And here is the code of the BigCalendar using this component

```html
<BigCalendar
    popup
    onNavigate={(focusDate, flipUnit, prevOrNext) => this.updateCalendarData(focusDate, prevOrNext)}
    onSelectEvent={(data) => this.showModalInfo(data)}
    events={this.state.data}
    views={['month', 'week', 'agenda']}
    components={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }} // <- Custom toolbar
/>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not positive on the TS parts, but I recently implemented a custom Toolbar myself. I copied the original Toolbar, and then adjusted it to do what I required. My custom stuff isn't that important, but this should show you how they originally implemented the `navigate` bits.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cn from 'classnames';
import ToolbarDateHeader from './ToolbarDateHeader.component';
import { Icon, Button, ButtonGroup, ButtonToolbar } from '../app';

const navigate = {
  PREVIOUS: 'PREV',
  NEXT: 'NEXT',
  TODAY: 'TODAY',
  DATE: 'DATE'
};

const propTypes = {
  view: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  views: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  localizer: PropTypes.object,
  onNavigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onView: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default class Toolbar extends Component {
  static propTypes = propTypes;
  render() {
    let {
      localizer: { messages },
      label,
      date
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button onClick={this.navigate.bind(null, navigate.TODAY)}>
            {messages.today}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.navigate.bind(null, navigate.PREVIOUS)}>
            <Icon glyph="caret-left" />
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.navigate.bind(null, navigate.NEXT)}>
            <Icon glyph="caret-right" />
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>

        <ToolbarDateHeader date={date} onChange={this.toThisDay}>
          {label}
        </ToolbarDateHeader>

        <ButtonGroup className="pull-right">
          {this.viewNamesGroup(messages)}
        </ButtonGroup>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }

  toThisDay = date => {
    this.props.onView('day');
    // give it just a tick to 'set' the view, prior to navigating to the proper date
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.onNavigate(navigate.DATE, date);
    }, 100);
  };

  navigate = action => {
    this.props.onNavigate(action);
  };

  view = view => {
    this.props.onView(view);
  };

  viewNamesGroup(messages) {
    let viewNames = this.props.views;
    const view = this.props.view;

    if (viewNames.length > 1) {
      return viewNames.map(name => (
        <Button
          key={name}
          className={cn({
            active: view === name,
            'btn-primary': view === name
          })}
          onClick={this.view.bind(null, name)}
        >
          {messages[name]}
        </Button>
      ));
    }
  }
}
```